# What does "punchout" mean in e-commerce?

Tags: meaning

I am doing e-commerce website development. Somebody often talks about Punchout Orders. But I have no idea about it.

Comment: See https://www.essent.com/What-is-a-PunchOut-Catalog.html

Comment: May be best suited for http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ecommerce

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are referring to ***[Procurement PunchOut](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procurement_PunchOut)*** :

> - the interaction between a vendor's web storefront and a buyer's procurement application. ***The buyer leaves or "punches out" of their company's system and goes to the supplier's web-based catalog to locate and add items to their shopping cart, while their application transparently maintains connection with the web site and gathers pertinent information***. A vendor catalog, enhanced for this process, is known as a punchout catalog. PunchOut enables communication between the software and the web site so that relevant information about the transaction is delivered to the appropriate channels.[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procurement_PunchOut) Sometimes, buyers and suppliers use intermediaries to ensure authentication.

(Wikipedia)